# Firefox goes back and forth upon highlighting text

Tags: firefox, mouse

When I select text by holding down the left mouse key and drag the mouse to the left, Firefox interprets it as if I had hit the **Back Button**. Same for the "left to right" move...

This makes editing in the browser (like this post) *very difficult*.

I have the plugin "mouse gestures redox 2.1.4" installed on Firefox 3.5.3 (Max OS 10.5.3). This used to be different the last few years...

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

By default Mouse Gestures Redox uses the right button for applying gestures.
It seems it's configured to work with the left button on your Firefox.

Check the option extensions:
Tools > Add-ons > Select Mouse Gestures Redox extension > Options button

In the General tab, under "Make Gestures with", make sure you have the "right button" radio button selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try running Firefox in safe mode.  If you still have the problem, it's a setting in Firefox.  If you don't have the problem, then it's the plugin's fault.

Answer (score 0):

Just a note related to your question: sometimes when using online editors such as [TinyMCE](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/), Firefox can get confused when using Delete/Backspace, or (on a Mac) when using Cmd-Left or Cmd-Right to go to the start or end of a line. Actually, the very same editor used on a different website might not show these problems. (Often these problems are related to some special dynamic loading of the editor, which then confuses the browser.)

To disable navigation using Delete/Backspace one can set the [Browser.backspace_action](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.backspace_action) preference.

To disable navigation using specific other keys, one can [use the keyconfig add-on](https://superuser.com/questions/24166/can-i-seize-control-of-cmd-left-in-osx/24199#24199).