# How can I disable the Backspace button's "Go Back" functionality in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

I am editing a lot of data in a web application using Firefox, and occasionally I hit the backspace key without focusing on a field, and FireFox goes back one page, erasing all the data I entered.

The developers of the application say that a box should come up asking me if I am sure I want to leave the page, because I have unsaved changes. That only works sometimes. Until they fix that behavior, what can I do on my local machine to disable the backspace button's "go back" functionality?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Navigate to **about:config** in the address bar
- set the filter to **browser.backspace_action**

It is an integer value, change it to the desired setting:

0 -  Pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will go back 1 page in session history and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will navigate forward 1 page in session history.

1 - Pressing <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will scroll the page up in the current document and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Backspace</kbd> will scroll it down.

**Any other positive integer (2 or more) will unmap the backspace key, which is what you want.** But keep in mind, the [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_%28computer_science%29) data type has a limit, so don't got crazy. 2 will be fine.

Comment: You're welcome! just keep in mind integers have a limit, so I'd just set it to 2 :)

Comment: That's very interesting. What are some other useful configurations you can with that way? Is there a list out there on the interwebs?

Comment: @wahle509 take a look at this other Superuser question - "What do you think is the most useful about:config setting in Firefox?" The best (useful) ones can be found in there. Link: http://superuser.com/questions/6647/what-do-you-think-is-the-most-useful-aboutconfig-setting-in-firefox

Answer (score 3):

- Type about:config into your firefox
  browser
- type in "backspace" in filter
- double click
  "browser.backspace_action" change the
  value 0 to 2.

Answer (score 2):

The keyconfig add-on [works for me](https://superuser.com/questions/40116/firefox-goes-back-and-forth-upon-highlighting-text/42044#42044) (though the [Browser.backspace_action](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.backspace%5Faction) preference might be sufficient for you).

Comment: Thanks -- this is a good easy alternative to about:config;

Answer (score 2):

The DisableBackspaceNavigation addon works as advertised: 
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1694

Comment: Thanks -- this is a good easy alternative to about:config;